# How can I use numpy to more efficiently modify the recorded sizes of nested sub-arrays, where the modification is condition-dependent?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, conditional-statements, counter

I have a working declustering algorithm that I would like to speed up using numpy. Given an array `a`, the consecutive differences `diffa` are obtained. Each of these consecutive differences are then checked to see whether each is greater or lesser than some threshold value `t_c`, which produces an array of `0`'s and `1`'s `False` and `True`. Taking into account that `diffa` is one index smaller than `a`, the counting schema is slightly modified. First, the size of each cluster of `0`'s and `1`'s is calculated as array `cl_size`. If the array contains `0`, then the size of the cluster is its original size plus one; if the array contains `1`, then the size of the cluster is its original size minus one. Below is an example that I would like to adapt for a much larger dataset.

```
import numpy as np

thresh = 21
a = np.array([1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 40, 70, 71, 72, 74, 100, 130, 160, 171, 200, 201])
diffa = np.diff(a)

print(diffa)
>> [ 1  3  5 10 20 30  1  1  2 26 30 30 11 29  1]

def get_cluster_statistics(array, t_c, func_kw='all'):
    """ This function separates clusters of datapoints such that the number
        of clusters and the number of events in each cluster can be known. """
    # GET CONSECUTIVE DIFFERENCES
    ts_dif = np.diff(array)
    # GET BOOLEAN ARRAY MASK OF 0's AND 1's FOR TIMES ABOVE THRESHOLD T_C
    bool_mask = np.array(ts_dif > t_c) * 1
    # COPY BOOLEAN ARRAY MASK (DO NOT MODIFY ORIGINAL ARRAY)
    bm_arr = bool_mask[:]
    # SPLIT CLUSTERS INTO SUB-ARRAYS
    res = np.split(bm_arr, np.where(abs(np.diff(bm_arr)) != 0)[0] + 1)

    print(res)
    >>[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1]), array([0]), array([1]), array([0])]

    # GET SIZE OF EACH SUB-ARRAY CLUSTER
    cl_size = np.array([res[idx].size for idx in range(len(res))])

    print(cl_size)
    >>[5 1 3 3 1 1 1] 

    # CHOOSE BETWEEN CHECKING ANY OR ALL VALUES OF SUB-ARRAYS (check timeit)
    func = dict(zip(['all', 'any'], [np.all, np.any]))[func_kw]
    # INITIALIZE EMPTY OUTPUT LIST
    ans = []
    # CHECK EACH SPLIT SUB-ARRAY IN RES
    for idx in range(len(res)):
        # print("res[%d] = %s" %(idx, res[idx]))
        if func(res[idx] == 1):
            term = [1 for jdx in range(cl_size[idx]-1)]
            # cl_size[idx] = cl_size[idx]-1
            ans.append(term)
        elif func(res[idx] == 0):
            # cl_size[idx] = cl_size[idx]+1
            term = [cl_size[idx]+1]
            ans.append(term)

    print(ans)
    >>  [[6], [], [4], [1, 1], [2], [], [2]]

    out = np.sum(ans)
    print(out)
    >>  [6, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2] 

get_cluster_statistics(a, thresh, 'any')
```

After this, I apply `Counter` via importable module `collections` to count the frequency of clusters of various sizes.

I am not sure how but I think there is a numpy solution that is more efficient, specifically in the section of code under `# CHECK EACH SPLIT SUB-ARRAY IN RES`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: still trying to figure out your get size section... but a[1:] - a[:-1] instead of np.diff and is there any reason you have split up most of your workflow into def's that largely do a calculation and return a value.  The code seems easier to read when they are removed and organized sequentially since most of the functions are only called once

Comment: Given a list of sub-arrays `res`, in which 0's and 1's are grouped together depending upon whether the consecutive difference is larger or smaller than a given threshold
`[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1]), array([0]), array([1]), array([0])]`

The array of sizes of each sub-array is then given as `cl_size [5 1 3 3 1 1 1]`. There are 5 differences but 6 elements of the original array that are grouped into 1st cluster. For each sub-array of 0's, add one; subtract one for 1's and split into singles; omit zero remainders. This gives `[6, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2] `

Comment: @NaN Aside from changing `np.diff` to `a[1:] - a[:1]`, I have edited the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: got sidetracked on np.sum([[6], [], [4], [1, 1], [2], [], [2]]) returning [6, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2] while [np.sum(i) for i in x] returns [6, 0.0, 4, 2, 2, 0.0, 2]